# ActionResult helper and different types resolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

Idea is to use same action methods for different types of results
I.E.

> /category/details/?resultFormat=json
>
> /category/details/?resultFormat=xml

So to have some kind of ActionResult helper that contains registered pairs of value resolvers

> "json", JsonValueResolver
>
> "xml", XmlResolver

etc...is there already solution for this or I have to think some kind of custom resolver?
Automapper has good solution for value resolving. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SmartResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        if (context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["ResultFormat] == "json")
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(this.Data));
        } else if(context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["ResultFormat] == "xml")
                    {
              ...serialize using xmlserializer
        }else{
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }

    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```